# Apache not starting with server reboot

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Apache is not starting when our server reboots.  How can I check to be sure it's being told to start with the server?

**update**

Sorry, I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Fedora/RedHat system:

chkconfig httpd on

On Debian/Ubuntu system:

update-rc.d apache defaults

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to, at the absolute least, specify what distribution you're using, assuming the "linux" tag is correct.

On CentOS/RHEL/FC, you're looking for:

```
chkconfig httpd on
```

For Debian, last time I did it, it was:

```
sysv-rc-conf
```

though that may have changed in more-recent versions.  For others, there are various ways to do it, but for any that use SysV init (which is nearly all of them), the process basically boils down to adding specially-named symlinks to a rc(X)[.y] directory (or two or three) that point at a master [init|rc] directory that contains the actual startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

FC/RedHat/CentOS

chkconfig httpd on

service httpd status